# Unity shader/C# - how to change colors of effect?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, visual-glitch

Ok so Im using this glitch effect (the analog one) that features a color "drift"

https://github.com/keijiro/KinoGlitch

It comes with a shader and this Analog Glitch script (all in link):

```
 [ExecuteInEditMode]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
    [AddComponentMenu("Kino Image Effects/Analog Glitch")]
    public class AnalogGlitch : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region Public Properties

        // Scan line jitter

        [SerializeField, Range(0, 1)]
        float _scanLineJitter = 0;

        public float scanLineJitter {
            get { return _scanLineJitter; }
            set { _scanLineJitter = value; }
        }

        // Vertical jump

        [SerializeField, Range(0, 1)]
        float _verticalJump = 0;

        public float verticalJump {
            get { return _verticalJump; }
            set { _verticalJump = value; }
        }

        // Horizontal shake

        [SerializeField, Range(0, 1)]
        float _horizontalShake = 0;

        public float horizontalShake {
            get { return _horizontalShake; }
            set { _horizontalShake = value; }
        }

        // Color drift

        [SerializeField, Range(0, 1)]
        float _colorDrift = 0;

        public float colorDrift {
            get { return _colorDrift; }
            set { _colorDrift = value; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Properties

        [SerializeField] Shader _shader;

        Material _material;

        float _verticalJumpTime;

        #endregion

        #region MonoBehaviour Functions

        void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
        {
            if (_material == null)
            {
                _material = new Material(_shader);
                _material.hideFlags = HideFlags.DontSave;
            }

            _verticalJumpTime += Time.deltaTime * _verticalJump * 11.3f;

            var sl_thresh = Mathf.Clamp01(1.0f - _scanLineJitter * 1.2f);
            var sl_disp = 0.002f + Mathf.Pow(_scanLineJitter, 3) * 0.05f;
            _material.SetVector("_ScanLineJitter", new Vector2(sl_disp, sl_thresh));

            var vj = new Vector2(_verticalJump, _verticalJumpTime);
            _material.SetVector("_VerticalJump", vj);

            _material.SetFloat("_HorizontalShake", _horizontalShake * 0.2f);

            var cd = new Vector2(_colorDrift * 0.04f, Time.time * 606.11f);
            _material.SetVector("_ColorDrift", cd);

            Graphics.Blit(source, destination, _material);
        }

        #endregion
```

I need to find out how to change the colors that it "glitches" in - as you can see right now it glitches green and magenta. I need red and blue but cant find specific color values.

I can post shader as needed - how can I achieve this glitch but in red/blue in unity?

SHADER:

```
Shader "Hidden/Kino/Glitch/Analog"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("-", 2D) = "" {}
    }
    CGINCLUDE

    #include "UnityCG.cginc"

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    float2 _MainTex_TexelSize;

    float2 _ScanLineJitter; // (displacement, threshold)
    float2 _VerticalJump;   // (amount, time)
    float _HorizontalShake;
    float2 _ColorDrift;     // (amount, time)

    float nrand(float x, float y)
    {
        return frac(sin(dot(float2(x, y), float2(12.9898, 78.233))) * 43758.5453);
    }

    half4 frag(v2f_img i) : SV_Target
    {
        float u = i.uv.x;
        float v = i.uv.y;

        // Scan line jitter
        float jitter = nrand(v, _Time.x) * 2 - 1;
        jitter *= step(_ScanLineJitter.y, abs(jitter)) * _ScanLineJitter.x;

        // Vertical jump
        float jump = lerp(v, frac(v + _VerticalJump.y), _VerticalJump.x);

        // Horizontal shake
        float shake = (nrand(_Time.x, 2) - 0.5) * _HorizontalShake;

        // Color drift
        float drift = sin(jump + _ColorDrift.y) * _ColorDrift.x;

        half4 src1 = tex2D(_MainTex, frac(float2(u + jitter + shake, jump)));
        half4 src2 = tex2D(_MainTex, frac(float2(u + jitter + shake + drift, jump)));

        return half4(src1.r, src2.g, src1.b, 1);
    }

    ENDCG
    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
            ZTest Always Cull Off ZWrite Off
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert_img
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 3.0
            ENDCG
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post shader?

Comment: Sure thing - is now in the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_ColorDrift` is used to generate a local variable in the shader called `drift`, this value is then only used in one location to generate the `src2` texture.

This texture is then used once, `return half4(src1.r, src2.g, src1.b, 1);`

Notice that the `src2` texture only supplies its Green value. This means that the green channel is offset (generating Green and Anti-Green (Magenta) distortions).

You can adjust this `return` line to generate Red/Anti-Red (Cyan) distortions or Blue/Anti-Blue (Yellow) distortions.  Just change which color value the `src2` variable applies to.

Red/Cyan:
`return half4(src2.r, src1.g, src1.b, 1);`

Blue/Yellow:
`return half4(src1.r, src1.g, src2.b, 1);`

Note that applying `src2` to *two* of the color channels just flip-flops the distortion (Red/Anti-Red -> Anti-Red/Red) and makes it more intense (the apparent distance the texture jumps is greater).